# jenkins - Non-resolvable parent POM for Could not find artifact and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Tags: maven, build, jenkins, pom.xml

I've got a problem concerning a build in jenkins. As the title describes it is an *"Non-resolvable parent POM for Could not find artifact and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM"* problem, found often on stackoverflow, but i haven't found a matching one. So here's my problem description

My project structure looks like this:

```
/root-project
 +-----------/pom.xml
/root-project/modul-a/
 +-------------------/pom.xml
/root-project/modul-b/
 +-------------------/pom.xml
/root-project/modul-c/
 +-------------------/pom.xml
```

On my local machine (windows) i can build my project from / with:

```
mvn -f root-project/pom.xml clean install
```

having no error, even with an empty repository.

But jenkins (linux) is not able to do this.

```
Gestartet durch Benutzer anonymous
Building in workspace /opt/jenkins/jobs/Project/workspace
Checkout:workspace / /opt/jenkins/jobs/Project/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@33333ab9
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision acb4c7d9efd81c1c7d5bbd2f6e190d1cb0a5e359 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from http://repository.git
Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen branch in repository origin/version_branch
Commencing build of Revision acb4c7d9efd81c1c7d5bbd2f6e190d1cb0a5e359 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checking out Revision acb4c7d9efd81c1c7d5bbd2f6e190d1cb0a5e359 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
[workspace] $ /opt/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn -f root-project/pom.xml -e clean install javadoc:aggregate
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 8 projects -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.example:rootartifact:pom:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 10
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.example:rootartifact:pom:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 11
//...
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:363)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:636)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:585)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:234)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.example:module-a:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (/opt/jenkins/jobs/Project/workspace/root-project/module-a/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.example:root-project:pom:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 10 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact org.example:root-project:pom:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT
```

So here's what's in my parent pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>root-project</artifactId>
<version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>module-a</module>
    <module>module-b</module>
```

And an example of a module pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>root-project</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
     //..
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

As mentioned in other entries i've tried  but it had not changed the result. Why should it, it points to the repository, where the parent has never been.
So does somebody has a suggestion what i'm doing wrong?

As asked here's the output of mvn help:effective-pom:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 3 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.example:modul-a:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (/tmp/project/project-root/modul-a/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.example:project:pom:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.example:modul-b:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (/tmp/project/project-root/modul-b/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.example:project:pom:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.example:modul-c:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (/tmp/project/project-root/modul-c/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.example:project:pom:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `<artifactId>` for your parent in your example module pom is **`root-project`**.

The `<artifactId>` in your parent pom is **`prject`**.  In the jenkins output, it appears the name of the artifact is being resolved to **`rootproject`**.  Try setting the parent's pom `<artifactId>` to **`root-project`** (note the extra '-').

I'm not sure how this builds on your machine.  Could you post the output from running `mvn help:effective-pom` on both your machine and the machine that is running jenkins?

For what it's worth, you can enable the `-X` flag for debug output to see actions Maven might be trying to take.  I have found this to be useful as I debug the configuration of my Maven projects.

Comment: First: i'm sorry this was an fault of my anonymization. The <artifactId> of the parent and the reference to the <artifactId> in the module are the ident. I'll correct it, and add the help:effective-pom output too. It's about the same - and making me crazy. Today a fresh checkout won't build on windows too ...

Comment: oh you were so close - found an other typo from an unseen commit ... thx